Unable to echo data under column which is enclosed in double quotes
I am trying to print the columns in a CSV file. The CSV file is as below:
Account,Data,Address,Name
A1101,100,"303,SCA,JDM",Ram
A1102,100,"303,SCA,JDM",Ram

And I have used the below Bash code to print the pattern.
patterns="$(cat csv_file3.csv |
            tail -n +2 |
            sort -k 2 |
            cut -d , -f 1,3,4 |
            uniq |
            tr -d ' ')"

echo "$patterns"

While I was executing in Git-Bash, the pattern is being printed as below:

As you can see, only a part of the 3rd column is being printed. Is it possible to print the format correctly? Below is the expected output.
    Account,Address,Name
    A1101,"303,SCA,JDM",Ram
    A1102,"303,SCA,JDM",Ram


cut doesn’t care about quotes. Use a proper CSV parser.

(You keep mentioning Bash, but the screenshot(!) shows you running sh. They are not the same thing.)

You are touching dangerous grounds: Now you are caring about the use of double quotes used for marking the extent of a whole field, but if this is a general CSV file, you will also have the possibility, that a field itself contains a double quote as value, or a field which contains a newline character. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, just use one of the many CSV parsers.

@Biffen No matter using bash or sh or tcsh or ksh. The problem is caused by cut, not by shell.

Try to solve it by Gawk:
$ gawk -k 'NR>=2{printf ("%s,\"%s\",%s\n", $1,$3,$4);}'  csv_file3.csv
A1101,"303,SCA,JDM",Ram
A1102,"303,SCA,JDM",Ram

cut -d,  will consider the "303 and JDM" is a single one field.  The GNU Awk -k option activates a CSV parser which knows how to cope with quoted fields.
